# Perl pattern match and arithmetic operation at the same time

Tags: regex, perl

Can i make match pattern and arithmetic operation at the same time ?

```
   print 5 / 3 !~ /\.\d*/;
```

result 5 , why ?

```
 $str = 5 / 3;
 print $str !~ /\.\d*/;
```

total correct.
How can i make in the one expression ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default order of operations is giving you the unexpected result. Instead, try:

```
print +(5 / 3) !~ /\.\d*/;
```

But, as pointed out by others, that's a terrible way to test whether 3 divides 5. You have the modulus operator for that:

```
print 5 % 3 == 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is returning 5 because `3 !~ /\.\d*/` returns `1` and 5 / 1 = 5`.

You can wrap your arithmetic expression in parens to have Perl evaluate it first:

```
print ((5 / 3) !~ /\.\d*/);
```

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks, I missed that one when testing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use brackets!

What happend in your code is basically:

```
print 5 / (3 !~ /\.\d*/);
```

So the RegEx comes first, then the `/` division.

I think you want to do something like:

```
print ((5 / 3) !~ /\.\d*/);

# or 

my $division = 5 / 3;
print $division if $division !~ /\.\d*/;
# or 
# print (5 / 3) if (5 / 3) !~ /\.\d*/; 
# but the calculation need to be twice here!
```

If i understand your problem correct, you just want to print if the division does not return a float:

```
print "test" if 5 / 3 == int 5 / 3
print "test 2" if 5 / 5 == int 5 / 5
```

Output:

```
test 2
```

There a way more better, faster and elegant ways to check this than using a RegExp.